USB HID Consumer Control using LUFA
I am using the LUFA keyboard demo, and for regular keystrokes it is working just fine. Unfortunately I cannot get media keys to work. My research online has pointed me towards modifying my HID descriptor to include a Consumer Control section, but I have not had any success.
Here is my original HID descriptor as provided by the LUFA keyboard demo. This works:
  HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x01),           // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
  HID_RI_USAGE(8, 0x06),                // Usage (Keyboard)
  HID_RI_COLLECTION(8, 0x01),           // Collection (Application)
  HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x07),   // Usage Page (Keyboard/Keypad)
  HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(8, 0xE0),// Usage Minimum (Keyboard Modifier)
  HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(8, 0xE7),// Usage Maximum (Keyboard Modifier)
  HID_RI_LOGICAL_MINIMUM(8, 0x00),
  HID_RI_LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(8, 0x01),
  HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x01),
  HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x08),
  HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_VARIABLE | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE),
  HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x01),
  HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x08),
  HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_CONSTANT),
  HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x08),   // Usage Page (LEDs)
  HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(8, 0x01),// Usage Minimum (Num Lock)
  HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(8, 0x05),// Usage Maximum (Kana)
  HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x05),
  HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x01),
  HID_RI_OUTPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_VARIABLE | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE | HID_IOF_NON_VOLATILE),
  HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x01),
  HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x03),
  HID_RI_OUTPUT(8, HID_IOF_CONSTANT),
  HID_RI_LOGICAL_MINIMUM(8, 0x00),
  HID_RI_LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(16, 0xFF),
  HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x07),   // Usage Page (Keyboard/Keypad)
  HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(8, 0x00),// Usage Minimum (Reserved)
  HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(8, 0xFF),// Usage Maximum (Reserved)
  HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 6),
  HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x08),
  HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_ARRAY | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE),
  HID_RI_END_COLLECTION(0),

Here is the associated working program logic for constructing the HID report (mute key does nothing):
bool CALLBACK_HID_Device_CreateHIDReport(USB_ClassInfo_HID_Device_t* const HIDInterfaceInfo,
                                         uint8_t* const ReportID,
                                         const uint8_t ReportType,
                                         void* ReportData,
                                         uint16_t* const ReportSize)
{
        USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t* KeyboardReport = (USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t*)ReportData;

        uint8_t UsedKeyCodes = 0;

        // encoder 1
        if (!(PINF & (1 << 6))) {
          KeyboardReport->KeyCode[UsedKeyCodes++] = K_H;
        } else if (!(PINF & (1 << 7))) {
          KeyboardReport->KeyCode[UsedKeyCodes++] = K_MEDIA_MUTE;
        }

        *ReportSize = sizeof(USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t);
        return false;
}

and the definition of the KeyboardReport struct:
                          typedef struct
                          {
                            uint8_t Modifier; /**< Keyboard modifier byte, indicating pressed modifier keys (a combination of
                                               *   \c HID_KEYBOARD_MODIFER_* masks).
                                               */
                            uint8_t Reserved; /**< Reserved for OEM use, always set to 0. */
                            uint8_t KeyCode[6]; /**< Key codes of the currently pressed keys. */
                          } ATTR_PACKED USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t;

Now, here is my attempt at including the Consumer Controls section. Full disclosure, I used AI tools for help with the descriptor.
    // Keyboard HID Report Descriptor
    HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x01),           // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
    HID_RI_USAGE(8, 0x06),                // Usage (Keyboard)
    HID_RI_COLLECTION(8, 0x01),           // Collection (Application)
    // Modifier byte
    HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x07),           // Usage Page (Keyboard/Keypad)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(8, 0xE0),        // Usage Minimum (Keyboard Left Control)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(8, 0xE7),        // Usage Maximum (Keyboard Right GUI)
    HID_RI_LOGICAL_MINIMUM(8, 0x00),      // Logical Minimum (0)
    HID_RI_LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(8, 0x01),      // Logical Maximum (1)
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x01),          // Report Size (1)
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x08),         // Report Count (8)
    HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_VARIABLE | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE), // Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    // Reserved byte
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x01),         // Report Count (1)
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x08),          // Report Size (8)
    HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_CONSTANT),    // Input (Constant)
    // LED report
    HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x08),           // Usage Page (LEDs)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(8, 0x01),        // Usage Minimum (Num Lock)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(8, 0x05),        // Usage Maximum (Kana)
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x05),         // Report Count (5)
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x01),          // Report Size (1)
    HID_RI_OUTPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_VARIABLE | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE | HID_IOF_NON_VOLATILE), // Output (Data, Variable, Absolute, Non-volatile)
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x01),         // Report Count (1)
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x03),          // Report Size (3)
    HID_RI_OUTPUT(8, HID_IOF_CONSTANT),   // Output (Constant)
    // Key arrays (6 bytes)
    HID_RI_LOGICAL_MINIMUM(8, 0x00),      // Logical Minimum (0)
    HID_RI_LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(16, 0xFF),     // Logical Maximum (255)
    HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x07),           // Usage Page (Keyboard/Keypad)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(8, 0x00),        // Usage Minimum (Reserved)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(8, 0xFF),        // Usage Maximum (Reserved)
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 6),            // Report Count (6)
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x08),          // Report Size (8)
    HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_ARRAY | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE), // Input (Data, Array, Absolute)
    HID_RI_END_COLLECTION(0),             // End Collection

    // Consumer Control HID Report Descriptor
    HID_RI_USAGE_PAGE(8, 0x0C),           // Usage Page (Consumer)
    HID_RI_USAGE(8, 0x01),                // Usage (Consumer Control)
    HID_RI_COLLECTION(8, 0x01),           // Collection (Application)
    HID_RI_LOGICAL_MINIMUM(8, 0x00),      // Logical Minimum (0)
    HID_RI_LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(16, 0x03FF),   // Logical Maximum (1023)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MINIMUM(16, 0x00),       // Usage Minimum (0)
    HID_RI_USAGE_MAXIMUM(16, 0x03FF),     // Usage Maximum (1023)
    HID_RI_REPORT_SIZE(8, 0x10),          // Report Size (16)
    HID_RI_REPORT_COUNT(8, 0x01),         // Report Count (1)
    HID_RI_INPUT(8, HID_IOF_DATA | HID_IOF_ARRAY | HID_IOF_ABSOLUTE), // Input (Data, Array, Absolute)
    HID_RI_END_COLLECTION(0)              // End Collection

Modified the KeyboardReport struct to add an additional field for the media key:
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t Modifier;      /**< Keyboard modifier byte, indicating pressed modifier keys (a combination of \c HID_KEYBOARD_MODIFER_* masks). */
    uint8_t Reserved;      /**< Reserved for OEM use, always set to 0. */
    uint8_t KeyCode[6];    /**< Key codes of the currently pressed keys. */
    uint16_t ConsumerControl; /**< Consumer control usage (for media keys). */
} ATTR_PACKED USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t;

Then I modified my the callback to fill in the ConsumerControl field when sending the mute key:
bool CALLBACK_HID_Device_CreateHIDReport(USB_ClassInfo_HID_Device_t* const HIDInterfaceInfo,
                                         uint8_t* const ReportID,
                                         const uint8_t ReportType,
                                         void* ReportData,
                                         uint16_t* const ReportSize)
{
        USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t* KeyboardReport = (USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t*)ReportData;

        uint8_t UsedKeyCodes = 0;

        // encoder 1
        if (!(PINF & (1 << 6))) {
          KeyboardReport->KeyCode[UsedKeyCodes++] = K_H;
        } else if (!(PINF & (1 << 7))) {
          KeyboardReport->ConsumerControl = K_MEDIA_MUTE;
        }

        *ReportSize = sizeof(USB_KeyboardReport_Data_t);
        return false;
}

When flashing FW, I am getting zero input in windows including regular keystrokes that were working before. I read that windows can be picky about byte alignment with composite HID descriptors, but I am not sure what exactly that means. Any help would be appreciated.
As a side question, could it be that windows is "remembering" the old HID descriptor and thus misbehaving? When plugging in the device after flashing the new FW, I no longer get the "Setting up _____" pop up. Just a suspicion...

You may need to separate your keyboard and consumer device reports into their own reports and identify each with a report id. I did it like that many moons ago and it seemed to work ok (although not all operating systems handled all consumer device usages). Have a look at https://github.com/abend0c1/irk/blob/master/smt/USBdsc.c
